# Show the ActionBar while scrolling up on a ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview, onscrolllistener

I have a `ListView` and when I scroll down or up I can detect this using this solution:

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) { }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        if(listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0)
            getActionBar().show();
        else
            getActionBar().hide();
    }
});
```

This way works and the `ActionBar` shows when the scroll comes back to the first item of the list. I would ALSO like to show the `ActionBar` again when I begin to scroll up within the list.

EDIT:

this is the last way and it works not always.. sometimes the actionbar disappears and never comes back:

```
private int mPreviousFirst;
...
listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) { }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
      if(prevVisibleItem != firstVisibleItem){
        if (firstVisibleItem < mPreviousFirst) 
            getActionBar().show();
         else 
            getActionBar().hide();

        mPreviousFirst = firstVisibleItem;
      }
    }
});
```

i'm close but something goes wrong :(

Comment: Can you review you post? I think some information are missing and these circumstances make it hard to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try manipulating the following onScrollChanged within your view,

[onScrollChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onScrollChanged(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

which keeps track of the current and previous states of a scroll.  If you are going up, then you could do the same behavior.

Something similar to the following would achieve what you are asking:

```
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged (int currentHorizontalPosition, int currentVerticalPosition, int oldHorizontalPosition, int oldVerticalPosition)
{
   if(currentVerticalPosition < oldVerticalPosition && positionDifference > threshold)
   {
       getActionBar().show();
   }
   else //condition for downscroll or other actions.
   {
       getActionBar().hide();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by saving the previous first visible position each time it changes:

```
private int mPreviousFirst;
...
listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) { }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        if (firstVisibleItem < mPreviousFirst) {
            getActionBar().show();
        } else if (firstVisibleItem > mPreviousFirst) {
            getActionBar().hide();
        }
        mPreviousFirst = firstVisibleItem;

    }
});
```

Comment: mmh.. Now it appears and disappears when it want :)

Comment: @End.Game I've updated my answer, it was wrong before. Note however that this is not the best way to do it.

Comment: @End.Game well to me it doesn't look too good. However it works. Just don't enable the fast scrolling as it tends to jump sometimes which would lead your actionbar to switch around.

Comment: yes, it works and the problem seems, as you are saying, the fast scrolling.. is it a good idea remove it?

Comment: @End.Game It's only the manual scrollbar that appears on the right (by default) which you use to scroll quickly a long list. It's disabled by default I believe.

Comment: ok, you're right.. My listview is without fastscroll by default.. So, how could i solve? I mean.. actually seems works but if i scroll fast up and down there are some problems.. But scrolling normally it works.

Comment: @End.Game you can apply some friction which will limit the amount the user can scroll in one swipe. (`listView.setFriction(0.25f)`. If you have further questions then you will have to ask another one.

Answer (score 0):

```
   mListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        int mLastFirstVisibleItem = 0;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {   }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (view.getId() == mListView.getId()) {
                final int currentFirstVisibleItem = mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

                if (currentFirstVisibleItem > mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
                    // getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide();
                    activity.hideActionBar();
                } else if (currentFirstVisibleItem < mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
                    // getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().show();
                    activity.showActionBar();
                }

                mLastFirstVisibleItem = currentFirstVisibleItem;
            }
        }
    });
```

this works for me on kitkat